# Hidden auto height and width automatically in wrapper by image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, height

I want to hidding height from image automatically
html:

```
<div class="category-thumbnail">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.thedeadtrees.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/linkin-park-environmental-efforts.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="opacity">
        <b>Jam Wanted</b>
        <p class="description">Boleh</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.category-thumbnail{
border: 1px solid red;
border-bottom: 8px solid red;
height: 250px;
```

}

in my local pc, the width is success but the height still overflow
and my compelete code here: https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/19tsojvz/

thankyou

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use "overflow: hidden;" property in category-thumbnail class. the image will be hidden automatically.

Answer (score 1):

just use `overflow:hidden;` in .category-thumbnail
https://jsfiddle.net/nk0a1bgp/